# I want to get a element by Text in beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("WEBSITE")
```

above code finds out element with a link text as WEBSITE, but I don't want to use Selenuim here and Find element by text by using bs4. I tried the following code but no results

```
elem = soup.find(text=re.compile('WEBSITE'))
```

Answer (score 0):

By the documentation provided [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=select#the-string-argument). You can do something like below.

```
ele = soup.find('tag', string='text_for_search')
```